# Calling a Fragment from another fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a slinding tab with 3 fragments in it. The first fragment has a button which should open a fragment under the same sliding tab.
I have the following view:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1QZMHJgpviceXlOWWFUdHdnTTQ/edit?usp=sharing

The final view i want on button click from above is as follows:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1QZMHJgpvicZzlSeXhLTFFlNE0/edit?usp=sharing

I tried using replace but the fragments overlap each other.

The code for the fragmentactivity, adapter and a fragment is as follows:

```
public class Slidingtab extends FragmentActivity implements
ActionBar.TabListener{

private ViewPager viewPager;
private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
private ActionBar actionBar;
// Tab titles
private String[] tabs = { "Post", "Recent", "Search" };
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_slidingtab);
    Log.d("Slding tab", "started");
    // Initilization
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    actionBar = getActionBar();
    mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);        

    // Adding Tabs
    for (String tab_name : tabs) {
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                .setTabListener((TabListener) this));
    }

    /**
     * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
     * */
    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            // on changing the page
            // make respected tab selected
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        }
    });
    Log.d("Slding tab", "ended");
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.slidingtab, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

Adapter

```
public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
    Log.d("adapter constructor", "started");
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int index) {
    Log.d("adapter", "started");
    switch (index) {
    case 0:
        // Top Rated fragment activity
        return new Homefragment();
    case 1:
        // Games fragment activity
        return new Recentfragment();
    case 2:
        // Movies fragment activity
        return new Searchfragment();
    }
    Log.d("adapter", "ended");
    return null;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // get item count - equal to number of tabs
    return 3;
}
}
```

HomeFragment

```
public class Homefragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d("Home fragment", "started");
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_homefragment, container, false);
    Log.d("Home fragment", "ended");
    return rootView;
}
}
```

I have the button in this fragment. I want the button click to open a fragment.
Any help?

Comment: Can you post your code here instead of linking to it?

Comment: new account. plus thats the screenshot of fragments

Comment: Any account can add code to their question, it's just text. Let's see what you've got so far and work off that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing your code, I can't tell definitively, but you can try something like this:

```
// Create new fragment and transaction
Fragment newFragment = new ExampleFragment();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

// Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
// and add the transaction to the back stack
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);

// Commit the transaction
transaction.commit();
```

Check out [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_fragments.htm) for more.

Comment: i tried this. The two fragments then overlap each other.